# Changing double variable to integer

Tags: r, variables, ggplot2, tidyverse

I am a beginner using R and I need a code to change a "dbl" variable to "integer"

I cannot find a code that works to change it I keep getting a error message. I am using tidy verse and will be using ggplot to visulise a boxplot and need the x axis to run 5-14 but right now it is running with the value codes (1-10). I have tried mutate function but I am unsure how to write that code that the codes change as above? Can someone please help?

Comment: Please `dput()` your data and copy the result into your question. Your issue needs to be reproducible. Also, copy the code you have tried into your question. Thanks

Comment: code I have tried is 

socialactiondata$`Year of School` %>% as.integer(socialactiondata$`Year of School`)

This only shows a list of lots of numbers but does not change the values from 1-10 to 5-14?

Year of school is variable name which has values which have been coded 1-10 but they should be 5-14 i.e. 1=5, 2=6, 3=7......

Answer (score 1):

Since no data was provided, I thought I'd just create something from scratch. It's pretty straightforward using `mutate` and `as.integer`.

I have no idea if I used the correct logic to get from the integer to year of school, but it sounds like it's close to what you described.

```r
socialactiondata <- tibble(fake_double = runif(n = 100, min = 1, max = 10))

socialactiondata %>%
  mutate(
    fake_integer = as.integer(fake_double), 
    year_of_school = fake_integer + 4 # no idea if this is the correct logic you need, but you can write it here
  )
```